# Improving speed when using a for loop for each user groups

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Suppose we have following dataset with the output window_num:

```
index    user1   date    different_months   org_different_months    window_num
1690289 2670088 2006-08-01  243.0                243.0                  1
1772121 2717874 2005-12-01  0.0                   0.0                   1
1772123 2717874 2005-12-01  0.0                   0.0                   1
1772125 2717874 2005-12-01  0.0                   0.0                   1
1772130 2717874 2005-12-01  0.0                   0.0                   1
1772136 2717874 2006-01-01  0.0                   0.0                   1
1772132 2717874 2006-02-01  0.0                  2099.0                 1
1772134 2717874 2020-08-27  0.0                   0.0                   4
1772117 2717874             0.0                   0.0                   4
1772118 2717874             0.0                   0.0                   4
1772128 2717874 2019-11-01  300.0                300.0                  3
1772127 2717874 2011-11-01  2922.0               2922.0                 2
1774815 2719456 2006-09-01  0.0                   0.0                   2
1774809 2719456 2006-10-01  0.0                  1949.0                 2
1774821 2719456 2020-05-20  0.0                   0.0                   7
1774803 2719456             0.0                   0.0                   7
1774806 2719456             0.0                   0.0                   7
1774819 2719456 2019-08-29  265.0                265.0                  6
1774825 2719456 2014-10-01  384.0                384.0                  4
1774812 2719456 2005-07-01  427.0                427.0                  1
1774816 2719456 2012-02-01  973.0                973.0                  3
1774824 2719456 2015-10-20  1409.0               1409.0                 5
```

The user number is represented by user1. The output is the window_num which is generated using different_months and orig_different_months columns. The different_months column is the difference between the date[n] and date[n+1].

Previously, I was using groupby.apply to output window_num, however it became extremely slow when the dataset increased. The code was improved considerably by using the shift functions on the entire dataset to calculate the different_months and  orig_different_months column, as well as applying the sort on entire dataset, as seen below:

```
  data = data.sort_values(by=['user','ContractInceptionDateClean'], ascending=[True,True])
  #data['user1'] =data['user']
  data['different_months'] = (abs((data['ContractInceptionDateClean'].shift(-1)-data['ContractInceptionDateClean'] ).dt.days)).fillna(0)
  data.different_months[data['different_months'] < 91] =0
  data['shift_different_months']=data['different_months'].shift(1)
  data['org_different_months']=data['different_months']
  
  data.loc[((data['different_months'] == 0) | (data['shift_different_months'] == 0)),'different_months']=0
  data = salesswindow_cal(data,list(data.user.unique()))
```

The code that I am currently struggling to improve the speed on is shown below:

```
def salesswindow_cal(data_,users):
    temp = pd.DataFrame()
    for u in range(0,len(users)):
        df=data_[data_['user']==users[u]]      
        df['different_months'].values[0]= df['org_different_months'].values[0]          
        df['window_num']=(df['different_months'].diff() != 0).cumsum()
        temp= pd.concat([df,temp],axis=0)        
    return pd.DataFrame(temp)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rule of thumb is not to loop through the users and extract `df = data_[data_['user']==user]`. Instead do `groupby`:

```
for u, df in data_.gropuby('user'):
    do_some_stuff
```

Another issue is not to concatenate data iteratively

```
data_out = []
for user, df in data.groupby('user'):
    do_some_stuff
    data_out.append(sub_data)

out = pd.concat(data_out)
```

In your case, you can do a function and `groupby().apply()` and pandas will concatenate the data for you.

```
def group_func(df):
    d = df.copy()
    d['different_months'].values[0] = d['org_different_months'].value[0]
    d['window_num'] = (d['different_months'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()

    return d

data.groupby('user').apply(group_func)
```

---

**Update**:

Let's try this vectorized approach, which **modifies** your data inplace

```
# update the first `different_months`
mask = ~data['user'].duplicated()
data.loc[mask, 'different_months'] == data.loc[mask, 'orginal_different_months']


groups = data.groupby('user')
data['diff'] = groups['different_months'].diff().ne(0)
data['window_num'] = groups['diff'].cumsum()
```

Comment: I will test out the speed using the above.

Comment: Hi I have tried groupby('user').apply(group_func), however this approach will be extremely slow. I have over a 1 million users.

Comment: Yes, `groupby().apply()` is slow, but still much faster than your loop. Let me show you another approach.

Comment: Using the vectorized approach works the best and the speed improved considerably.